# how to convert speed to angle

Tags: data-conversion, degrees

I am programming a speedometer for cars. I get the current speed in km/h from another system and I am displaying it in the digital version of the speedometer. Now I have to show the same amount on the non-digital version of the speedometer. How do I do that? what is the formular to convert speed into degrees? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not really a programming question. You want http://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: And there is no formula. It's a proportion of an arc, the length of which depends on the design of your speedo.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "speed to angle" conversion